# When does an ajax request in jquery consider an http post request successful?

Tags: php, ajax

**Here is an excerpt from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) on http responses:**

**10.2 Successful 2xx**

> This class of status code indicates that the client's request was
>   *successfully received, understood, and accepted.*

**10.2.1 200 OK**

The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:

GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the response;

POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;

Is it considered "received, understood, and accepted" when the $_POST[] variables are stored in some other variable?

**EDIT:** here is the ajax call which calls an empty php file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&zone='+zone,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
                 event.id = response.eventid;
                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                },
    error:  function(e){
                alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                }
  });
```

and it calls the error part of the ajax call. But the console shows no errors.  **Now why it chooses only error and not success ??**

Comment: A php script will by default give a 200 OK, you will have to manually set the response code to something else if needed `http_response_code(401);` This would trigger a failure handler/callback instead of the success handler/callback of your ajax call - where you could show some "You must be logged in to do that" message.

Comment: problem is that the ajax request returns error: and not success even when the target php file is empty.

Comment: Please post the code you have for the ajax request. Do you get an error returned? Post that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to store anything... it's only about the response code.
For example I can make a POST to a "script" that doesn't process anything, just a dummy empty file...

I don't really understand what's your "dilemma".

Comment: I'm making an ajax call and it is responding raw html. as you said I emptied my target php file, but was not sure if the $.ajax call will handle it as success or an error! Unfortunately It called the function contained in the " <error :>  part.

Comment: please edit the question to answer it  so that i can accept it.